# Copy and pasting a file from a Dropbox folder to current folder via batch file (.bat)

Tags: file, batch-file, directory, dropbox, xcopy

I am currently trying to get a batch file to create folders and populate certain folders with a template file which can be grabbed from a template folder via Dropbox dir.

Here is a sample of the code I am trying to figure out:

```
md Sales
cd Sales
md "01_Final Issue""
md "02_Contracts"
md "03_Estimates"
xcopy "%CD%\Dropbox (G-SMATT EUROPE)\G-SMATT Europe Projects\Templates\Tester2017.xls" "CD" 
md "04_Presentations"
md "05_Briefing Materials" 
cd..
```

The actual dir is `D:\AshleyGlover\Dropbox (G-SMATT EUROPE)\G-SMATT Europe Projects\Templates`.
As the script will be run of from other machines I need to make sure that user name and the drive letter is a variable.

I am not having any luck with getting the file copied and pasted to the 03_Estimates folder. Any idea on how this can be done, as I am starting to hit my head against the wall.

Comment: Please review [Ask].

Comment: The "CD" target directory on your xcopy line looks suspect.  Preserve your sanity, stop 'cd'ing in your script and define some source and target directory variables, then use those on your xcopy lines.